# Seeking References on Deterministic and Stochastic Phenomena Suitable for High School Students

Tags: secondary-education, examples, probability

Can anyone recommend good and didactic references that delve into the dualism between deterministic and stochastic phenomena? Ideally, I'm seeking materials that provide a conceptual explanation along with numerous examples suitable for high school students.

to define what is a random phenomena is not easy as point out this article [What Is a Random Sequence?by Sérgio B. Volchan](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2002.11919838)

also, see these videos : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rIy0xY99a0 and
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sMb00lz-IfE

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking for resources is not a valid kind of question for this site.

Comment: @Dominique Why??? It seems to be directly pertinent to math. education and there are several requests of that type on the site, the most prominent (but by no means unique) being https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10636/source-of-conceptual-multiple-choice-calculus-questions

Comment: @Dominique, I think as many resources an educator have. a better educator he/she can be. please do not close my question.

Answer (score 1):

There was a question "is throwing dice a deterministic or stochastic process" on Physics.SE a while back, and I think [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/477980) is insightful and accessible enough to spur a good discussion amongst a class of high schoolers who have some baseline amount of interest in the distinction.

An excerpt:

> Throwing dice is just throwing dice. That's all. It's not stochastic, nor deterministic. It's just throwing dice.
>
> Now we model throwing dice as a process, and that's where the stochastic or deterministic side starts to play in. It is the process that is stochastic or deterministic, not the throwing of the dice. It's how we think about the throwing of dice that can be stochastic or deterministic.
>
> ... continued [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/477980)

Comment: Maybe flippant: to the degree that a process is not deterministic, it is stochastic.